# Highstocks Plotline multi-color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highstocks chart that shows events on a timeline.  These events are represented by multiple different series of data, and I want to show the line between events in different colors representing past/future (not relating to the series themselves).

Using `plotOptions.series.lineWidth: 8` results in a chart looking like this, due to the colors associated with different series (some of which contain only a single point):

[image]

If I set `plotOptions.series.lineWidth: 0` and specify a plotline, I can achieve the desired view:

[image: 8px-high plotline]

**My question**:

Is it possible to:

- Show a y-axis plotline in 2 different colors depending on x-axis value? or
- Create 2 y-axis plotlines and only partially display each? or
- Draw shaded *rectangles* behind the markers rather than entire bands/lines?

to create something like this (assuming today was early 2021):

[image: Desired plotline]

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/2) No, plotLine can contain single color, and you cannot limit widht of it

You can use renderer to add custom lines. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path